# How to convert non-built-in types to string in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a module that convert something like x:int = if true then 3 else 5 to a string

Here's the code I have so far

```
module Ast =
struct

type typ = Bool | Int
type var = A | B | C | D | E | F
type exp = Const of int * typ
           | App of string * exp list
           | If of exp * exp * exp
           | And of exp * exp
           | Or of exp * exp
       | Id of var * typ * exp


let rec toString (t) =
    let formatDec1(va,ty,e) = ???
    match t with
    Const(n, _) -> print_int n
      | App(id, [e1; e2]) -> formatter(" " ^ id ^ " ", e1, e2)
      | App(id, [e1]) -> formatter(" " ^ id ^ " ", e1, Const(0, Int))
      | App(id, _) -> formatter(" " ^ id ^ " ", Const(0, Int), Const(0, Int))
      | If(e1, e2, e3) -> formatIf(e1, e2, e3)
      | And(e1, e2) -> formatter(" && ", e1, e2)
      | Or(e1, e2) -> formatter(" || ", e1, e2)
      | Id(va,ty,e) -> formatDecl(va,ty,e)
end
```

I'm still a beginner in OCaml and couldn't find anything about converting to a string online. Thanks!

Comment: what would be the result in your example?

Comment: like " x:int = if true then 3 else 5". not sure if the toString function I have so far is on the right track.

Comment: so you want the pretty printed symbolic expression, with the ml syntax.  there are libraries to deal with so called *sexp*, but I don't know how 's the string representation.

Comment: you're somewhat close with what you already have, but there are some syntactic errors in your code.

Comment: the `App` arm of your exp type is very general: you can define application of any number of arguments, so the toString function should reflect that. In your code, it doesn't take care of the general case.

Comment: you also don't define what formatter and formatIf are.

Comment: If you want to use complex pretty printers, have a look at the Format module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to pretty print symbolic expressions, with the ml syntax. There are libraries to deal with so called sexp, but I never used them, I cannot comment on their uses, and it's probably not what you want, as it would sidestep the purpose of the exercise.

I think you're somewhat close with what you already have, but there are some syntactic errors in your code. I'll give you a bunch of advices to help you close the gap.

**First, regarding the OCaml syntax:**

Recall that you don't need to use parentheses for your function argument. The general syntax for a function definition is:

```
let fun_name arg1 arg2 arg3 = function_body
```

if you write

```
let fun_name (arg1,arg2,arg3) = ...
```

you are actually defining a function taking 1 argument, which is itself a tuple of 3 values.

Within an expression, you can define local values using the `let ... in` construct, just like when you define top level values (like I did above). If these value definitions aren't inter-dependant, you can use the `and` keyword between several value definitions.

For instance,

```
let x = 1 
and y = "a" in
...
```

would define 2 values `x` and `y` which may be used in the subsequent code.

**In your code**

The types you have give a little symbolic expression language, with which you can define expressions like the one you give in example:

"x:int = if true then 3 else 5" would be:

```
Id("x", 
   Int, 
   (If (Const (1, Bool), 
        Const (3, Int), 
        Const (5, Int))))
```

Indeed, you need to go through that value recursively, and combine the returned strings into a bigger string. Alternatively, you could use a string list, and do the string concatenation at the end.
Looking at that example, you probably can see how this would work:

```
"x" ^ (":" ^ "int") ^ "=" ^ ("if" ^ ("true") ^ "then" ^ ("3") ^ ("5"))
```

You can see the different sub expressions patterns in the above. I used parentheses to denote them.

In your toString function, there are 3 undefined values:

- `formatter` (a function taking a 3-tuple of type `string * exp * exp`)
- `formatDec1` (another function taking a 3-tuple of type `exp * exp * exp`)
- `formatIf` (same as `formatDec1`)

You used the keyword `rec` in your `toString` function definition, indicating that the function is recursive. In my opinion, you don't need the 3 functions above (are they a part of your initial assignment, or did you define them by yourself?), but just the `toString` function and string concatenation there.

the `App` arm of your `exp` type is very general: you can define application of any number of arguments, so your string conversion code should take that possibility in account. You could use some list function (`fold_left` comes to mind) to take care of it.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. But I got one more question. How can I use pattern matching to convert non-primitive types to string because obviously I can't do "x" -> "x" because it will just be x for whatever symbol it is

Comment: I'll give you a example: the  `And (e1,e2)` arm of `toString` should probably be something like `And (e1,e2) -> toString e1^" && "^toString e2`. That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a project named [deriving](http://code.google.com/p/deriving/) that can help generate printing functions automatically. I haven't used it, but it looks good.

It would be very cool to see something like this added to the base OCaml compiler. It works very well in Haskell (which is where the name "deriving" comes from).

Comment: Thank you but I just found out I'm required first convert the whole thing to a string, which is a whole different topic. Sorry about that.

Comment: The deriving project can also generate strings from values, according to the documentation I just looked at. (On the other hand, I'm not sure the project has been updated for the latest OCaml.)

Comment: Deriving works with 4.00.1 for me. Let's not forget about sexplib as well.

Comment: Awesome, good to hear that deriving is up to date! I use sexplib, but I think of it as a way to externalize data, not as a way to print it. However, it is quite readable and I often do end up looking at it.

Comment: the to_string function in deriving is too complex. i don't think we need to use something like that for a beginner's class. is there a more straightforward way to just convert non-primitive to a string? learning ocaml has been frustrating. there just isn't enough sources for beginners. thanks for your help

Comment: Well, it's tedious but not so hard to just write your own printing functions as Basile suggested. This is what I have always done, in fact.

Comment: One final option for this is to use the builtin dump function that comes with batteries. However it's not perfect and only useful for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement your own printing routines for your types (or for aggregate types, made of records or products of printable types).

You may want to use the `%a` conversion specification of the module [Printf](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) which accepts a printing function in addition to the argument to be printed.

If using the interactive `ocaml` top-level interpreter, you may want to use the `#install_printer` [toplevel directive](http://aml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual023.html).

In your code, you want to recursively call `format` (e.g. for the `And(e1, e2)` pattern case).

For printing to strings, use `Printf.sprintf` or [Format](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html)`.sprintf` and friends. Both `Printf` and `Format` modules give you other abilities (printing to a channel, to a buffer, to a string, etc..)

Comment: Thank you but I just found out I'm required first convert the whole thing to a string, which is a whole different topic. Sorry about that.

Comment: I tried Printf.sprintf ("%a") but it's (unit -> '_a -> string) -> '_a -> string . I've never encountered anything like unit -> 'a. Could you give me an example? This is my first time using printf.

Comment: `%a` needs two arguments (the first being a function). Read the `Printf` or `Format` module documentation.